# Changing font in Window created in python code

Tags: python, pygtk

Changing font in Window created in python code.

I have some working python code that shows the MMDDYYYY HH:MM:ss in a window I would like to add additional text above the date and time along with increasing the size of the font (of the data and time MMDDYYYY HH:MM:SS).  I tried to add different text and font size but it would stop my code from working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import time

class Clock:

    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.set_title("mmddyyyyhhmmss-Clock")
        self.label = gtk.Label()
        window.add(self.label)
        window.set_border_width(10)
        window.show_all ()

    def update(self):

        self.label.set_text(time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H%M%S'))
        return True  #needed to keep the update method in the schedule

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clock = Clock()
    gtk.timeout_add(200, clock.update)  #add to the main loop scheduled tasks
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using markup most likely will do what you need. First, enable it on the label. Then instead of using `set_text`, use `set_markup`:

```
self.label.set_use_markup(True)
t = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H%M%S')
self.label.set_markup('<span size="18000">The time:</span> ' + t)
```

As a reference: the markup language used by GTK is [Pango](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/pango-markup-language.html).

Comment: I added your suggestion but nothing seems to have changed any idea what I'm doing wrong?

 def update(self):
  self.label.set_use_markup(True)
  t=time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H%M%S')
  self.label.set_markup('<span size="100">The time:</span> ' + t)
  return True #needed to keep the update method in the schedule

Comment: For one, the font size was too small (changed it to 18000 as Pango used thousandths of points). This should work, actually... I look at the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklabel.html#id3773080) again, and the above is correct. You could try it with different tags (e.g. replace the `span` with `b`). Alternatively, place the `set_markup` function in your `__init__`: perhaps there's a problem with the updating?

Comment: `set_text` should also work with markup, after doing `label.set_use_markup(True)`

Comment: Thanks that did it with the '<span size="18000"